# scraping src attribute value with xPath,

Tags: php, xpath

There are images I want to scrape, using xPath as scraping tool. But xPath can't find the `src` attributes although I can see the attributes in the sources code of the website.

Normally I should fine the image's attribute, but xPath returns nothing.

```
$html = pageContent($link."photo");
$path = new \DOMXPath($html);
$route = $path->query("//ul[@class='categoryBox']//li[@class='photoList_item']/a/img");
foreach($route as $val){
    $images[] = trim($val->getAttribute("src"));
}

var_dump($images);
```

the website is: https://hana-yume.net/174/photo/ you can check the path here.

What are the possible reasons?

And if you need to see `pageContent()` function here:

```
function pageContent(String $url): \DOMDocument
{
    $html = cache()->rememberForever($url, function () use ($url) {

        $opts = array(
            "http" => array(
            "method"=>"GET",
            "header"=>"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"
            )
        );

        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        $result = @file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
        return $result;
    });

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

    $parser = new \DOMDocument();
    $parser->loadHTML($html = mb_convert_encoding($html,"HTML-ENTITIES", "ASCII, JIS, UTF-8, EUC-JP, SJIS"));
    return $parser;
}
```

Comment: A lot of sites load data dynamically using JS once the page is loaded.  A simple test is when you have read the page in your code is to save `$html` to a local file and then have a look at the file - not in a browser as this may trigger the JS!  Check the file for the source you are expecting and if it is not present then check the JS.

Comment: what you mean is I can't reach the `attributes` if the attributes aren't in the `$html` @NigelRen

Comment: The whole world is lacking in equality these days … and so is your code, with `ul[@class'categoryBox']` – the `=` is missing!

Comment: it's very much typo actually. not the problem's source :) sorry about the that. @misorude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the typo fix above, since its dynamically loaded for lazy-loading purposes, you need to target it in another way.

If you carefully examine:

```
<a data-lightbox="tile10" href="/uploads/hall_photo/174/1/0/main_0.jpg?1566895565" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'kanto', 'hall/photo', 'photo/1_0_main0_174', 1, {nonInteraction: true});">
    <img alt="アニヴェルセル 柏 挙式会場" width="750" height="330" class="lazy" data-original="/uploads/hall_photo/174/1/0/main_0_s.jpg?1566895565" />
    <noscript><img alt="アニヴェルセル 柏 挙式会場" width="750" height="330" src="/uploads/hall_photo/174/1/0/main_0_s.jpg?1566895565" /></noscript>
</a>
```

The `<img>` tag isn't static, meaning on load its not present but manipulated by JS. But as you can see, the source is still there.

So just target the data attribute instead:

```
$html = pageContent('https://hana-yume.net/174/photo/');
$path = new \DOMXPath($html);
$images = [];
$route = $path->query("//ul[@class='categoryBox']//li[contains(@class, 'photoList_item')]/a/img");
foreach($route as $val){
    $images[] = trim($val->getAttribute('data-original'));
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer. I don't know what is your output. but in mine returns empty...

Comment: @mr.hello il setup a fiddle in a minute

Comment: @mr.hello https://www.tehplayground.com/dr0WPCC96aT4HpX0 here just follow it, it should be fairly the same. just press "Run" on the fiddle to execute the code

Comment: yes it's very much working on fiddle. I guess I messed up something on backward. But thank you for pointing out a different path.

Comment: @mr.hello i just modified the function you made since in the sandbox demo there's no `cache()->rememberForever()` method there. but I think you get it now, just simply target it in either the data attribute or even the noscript tag -> img tag with src too, it'll work the same. glad this helped

Comment: yep, fix the code and it's working on mine too.. thank you.